# Assign a image id with php by total count of images

Tags: php, html

Im trying to assign a id for each image returned from the database. The id will then be put into img id. The id needs to be from the total count of the number of database rows returned.

```
<?php 
while ($result  = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$imgURL = $result['imageUrl'];
$imgID = mysql_num_rows($query);

for ($i=0; $i <= $imgID; $i++) { 
}

echo"<img id =\"$i\" src=\"uploads/$imgURL\"/>";
}

?>
```

What i get in return is the images are displayed from the database, but instead of img id being sequential numbers (ie 1, 2, 3 etc.) it just returns me the total count. How can I get it to assign a individual number in order for each image returned?

All help is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to calculate the number of rows or have multiple loops. Just let `$i` be incremented with each pass of the while loop.

```
$i = 0;
while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $imgURL = $result['imageUrl'];
    echo '<img id ="' . $i . '" src="uploads/' . $imgURL . '" />';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your echo inside your for loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i <= $imgID; $i++) { 
    echo "<img id =\"$i\" src=\"uploads/$imgURL\"/>";
}
```

EDIT:
As an aside, you might not want to identify your images that way. The order of records in your query might not stay consistent depending on your application logic. Each record should have a unique ID in the database and that value would be preferable to the iteration count.

Comment: I tried that @davidethell but what I get in return is, say for instance I have 5 images in the database, it would return the five images, five times, with the id's of each image as "0,1,2,3,4,5". How do i get it to only return 5 images, and have the first image be 1, the second image 2, etc.?

Comment: If you don't care about the actual database ID and just want a sequential count then just keep your for loop logic and put LIMIT 5 on your query.

Answer (score 0):

You have a bracket in the wrong place. I have rewritten it for you:

```
<?php 
while ($result  = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $imgURL = $result['imageUrl'];
    $imgID = mysql_num_rows($query);

    for ($i=0; $i <= $imgID; $i++) { 
        echo "<img id =\"$i\" src=\"uploads/$imgURL\"/>";
    }
}
?>
```

You might also some consistency problems unless the ID comes from a field in the database. If your query does not have a sort, then you are not guaranteed any particular ordering. The most common way of rectifying this is to create another field called "id", and give it the auto_increment attribute. This way it will give you a unique sequential number that will never change. You can also sort by this number.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this. The thing you've done is completely useless, because you are doing the same thing again and again in the same row:

```
<?php
$imgID = 0;
while ($result  = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$imgURL = $result['imageUrl'];
echo"<img id =\"$imgID\" src=\"uploads/$imgURL\"/>";
$imgID = $imgID + 1;
}

?>
```